# calling python code from java: askopenfilename does not work

Tags: java, python, tkinter

I have a java program that calls a Python tkinter UI.

it calls it like such:

```
Button button = new Button("Visualize Differences");
        pane.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String pypath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\source\\vchange\\viz.py";
                    
                String[] cmd = {
                          "python",
                          pypath,
                };
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

the python program then takes user input using askopenfilename

```
def startcompare():
    try:
        t = threading.Thread(target=startPython.build(xml_old.get(),xml_new.get(),out_xml.get()))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Title", "Error. Please enter valid path")

def browsefunc1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = path,filetypes=(("xml files","*.xml"),("All files","*.*")))
    ent1.delete(0, 'end')
    ent1.insert(tk.END, filename) # add this

def browsefunc2():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = path,filetypes=(("xml files","*.xml"),("All files","*.*")))
    ent2.delete(0, 'end')
    ent2.insert(tk.END, filename) # add this

def browsefunc3():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = path,filetypes=(("xml files","*.xml"),("All files","*.*")))
    ent3.delete(0, 'end')
    ent3.insert(tk.END, filename) # add this
    
l0 = tk.Label(root,text = 'Enter XML files for visualization.')

l1 = tk.Label(root,text = 'old entry:')

ent1=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=xml_old)

l2 = tk.Label(root,text = 'new entry:')

ent2=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=xml_new)

l3 = tk.Label(root,text = 'out.xml:')

ent3=tk.Entry(root,textvariable=out_xml)

b1=tk.Button(root,text="...",command=browsefunc1)

b2=tk.Button(root,text="...",command=browsefunc2)

b3=tk.Button(root,text="...",command=browsefunc3)

b4=tk.Button(root,text="OK",command=startcompare)

b5=tk.Button(root,text="Cancel",command=root.destroy)
```

However, when I launch startcompare method: it gives an error.

[image]

Doing the same thing, the error does not happen when I launch it from IDLE instead of the Java program.

Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

As far as I can work out, it probably has to do with my StartPython file.
StartPython is in the same folder as the UI code and works fine when launching from IDLE.

Thanks in advance

**====================================EDIT==================================**
Printing the error message I get the following:
[image]

tmp.png is an image I am using in StartPython.
However, The files are all in the same directory:
[image]

The part in StartPython that uses tmp.png is like this:

```
image_filename = 'tmp.png'
```

Do I have to change this value?

Comment: Try not using the `try / except` statements inside `startcompare()` function in order to see the actual exception raised.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for the response! I have gotten the exception raised and added more details to the question.

Comment: It may be because the *current directory* is not the directory of `startPython.py`.

Comment: @acw1668 How do I make it such that they are all in the 'current directory'?

Comment: Better use full path name inside `startPython.py`: `image_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'tmp.png')`.  Of course you need to add `import os` inside `startPython.py` as well.